# Connect multiple database in controller or model Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want connect over database
because dbHost, dbUser, dbPass... is Variable should i want connect it in controller or model. 
In controller file or model file, What should I write?

Comment: This may help http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

In config.php file set as follow:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db1';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['db2']['username'] = '';
$db['db2']['password'] = '';
$db['db2']['database'] = 'db2';
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Or where you want to use directly do as follow:

```
$db2 = $this->load->database("database_name);
```

in active record:

```
$this->db2->select("*");
```

Comment: Do you want to use database directly?

Comment: Check out this part of the manual: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: ['hostname'],['username'],['password'],['database']... it doesn't hardcode. it's variable conductive.

Answer (score 0):

It's in `database.php` in `applications/config/` directory not `config.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without adding to any file

1)We need to create DB Driver String from your given parameters
**dbdriver://username:password@hostname/database**
//Controller function

```
function connnectExternalDB()
{
    $dbdriver = $this->input->get_post('dbdriver'); //mysqli or mysql
    $username = $this->input->get_post('username'); // DB user name
    $password = $this->input->get_post('password'); // DB password
    $hostname = $this->input->get_post('hostname'); // DB host url
    $database = $this->input->get_post('database'); // DB name
    $dsn_string = "$dbdriver://$username:$password@$hostname/$database";
    // Following will overwrite your current DB connection
    $this->load->database($dsn_string, FALSE, TRUE); // 2nd parameter will return db object,3rd parameter will return active record enable for this db connection;
    $this->load->model("example_model");

}
```

2) You can do the same without overwriting the current db connection like this

```
function connnectExternalDB()
{
    $dbdriver = $this->input->get_post('dbdriver'); //mysqli or mysql
    $username = $this->input->get_post('username'); // DB user name
    $password = $this->input->get_post('password'); // DB password
    $hostname = $this->input->get_post('hostname'); // DB host url
    $database = $this->input->get_post('database'); // DB name
    $dsn_string = "$dbdriver://$username:$password@$hostname/$database";
    // Following will overwrite your current DB connection
    $DB_OBJ = $this->load->database($dsn_string, TRUE, TRUE); // 2nd parameter will return db object,3rd parameter will return active record enable for this db connection;
    $query = "select * from user";
    $user_list = $DB_OBJ->query($query)->result_array();
}
```