# Codeigniter routing url

Tags: codeigniter

I checked the similar questions out there, but those doesn't seem to help.

I have a site and the base url is : (http://localhost/myproject). I will make it as SAAS to be accessed by registered users and each user will has own domain like : (http://localhost/myproject/user1) and etc. When user registered the system will generate database with same domain for each user, so when each user access his own domain it will connect to his database also. The question is how to control routing for each user when he type his own doamin and set all url in the system. I tried a lot but didn't found the solution. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://localhost/myproject/user1 this is not an own domain. Separate domain would be http://user1.myproject.localhost/.  Have you read that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392816/connect-multiple-database-in-controller-or-model-codeigniter

Comment: It didn't help me. Any other ways please.any method to control routes from subdomains as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create vanity url with the username
Try remapping the controller

Controller

```
    class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $method)) {
            $this->$method($params);
        } else {
            array_unshift($params, $method);
            $this->user_detail($params);
        }
    }

    public function user_detail($params) {
        $username = $params[0];
        echo 'username: ' . $username;
    }

    public function another_func() {
        echo "another function body!";
    }
}
```

You can read up from here : [How to route cutom URL with to custom controller in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083439/how-to-route-cutom-url-with-to-custom-controller-in-codeigniter)

> Though this will give you something like this
>   http://www.localhost/myproject/user/user_detail/john => 'username:
>   john'

Try updating your routes like this routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user/user_detail/$1";
```